# On the convergence of operators and their spectra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-operators, homogenization

We consider a sequence of operators $\{L_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Each operator $L_n$ is a densely defined (possibly unbounded) closed linear operator on a real Hilbert space $H_n.$ The domain of $L_n$ is denoted by $\text{Dom}(L_n).$

Let $(L,\text{Dom}(L))$ be a self-adjoint operator on a real Hilbert space $H$.
We say that the sequence of operators $\{L_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $L$ if for every $f \in \text{Dom}(L)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $f_n \in \text{Dom}(L_n)$ such that
\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty}\|\pi_nf-f_n\|_n=0\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{n \to \infty}\|\pi_n(Lf)-L_nf_n\|_n=0.
 \end{align*} Here  $\|\cdot\|_n$ denotes a norm on $H_n$, and $\pi_n \colon H \to H_n$ is an invertible bounded linear operator such that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\|\pi_n\|_n<\infty$ and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\|E_n\|_n<\infty$. Here, $E_n$ is  the inverse operator of $\pi_n$. We also write $\|\pi_n\|_n$ and $\|E_n\|_n$ for  the  operator norms  of $\pi_n$ and $E_n$, respectively.

**Question**

We assume that the operator  $(L,\text{Dom}(L))$ is nonnegative. That is, $\langle Lf,f \rangle \ge 0$ for every $f \in \text{Dom}(L).$ Then, can we show that there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\langle L_n f,f \rangle_n \ge M\tag{$\ast$}
\end{equation}
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f \in \text{Dom}(L_n)$ ?
Here, $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_n$ denote the inner product on $H$ and $H_n$, respectively.

The condition $(\ast)$ imply the spectra of the operators  $\{L_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are uniformly bounded below.

Comment: These assumptions hold for arbitrary operators $L,L_n$: we can take $\pi_n,f_n=0$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you  for the comment. I should assume that $\pi_n$ is nontrivial.

Comment: That won't help, you could also take $\pi_n=1/n$. I think at the very least, you'd need the $\pi_n$ to be invertible with uniform bound on the inverses.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you for your comment. Certainly there should be such an assumption.